# PrintStream doesn't print

Tags: java, printstream

```
in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
ps = new PrintStream(out);

public void run() {
    String line;    

    try {
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null && line.length()>0) {
            System.out.println("got header line: " + line);
        }
        ps.println("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ps.println("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
    ps.println("<HTML> <HEAD>hello</HEAD> </HTML>");
}
```

The program runs without errors and ps.println does not print anything to the browser.
Any idea why?

Comment: Where does the `client` object come from?

Comment: There is no point using DataOutputStream and PrintStream together. You can remove DataOutputStream.

Comment: I removed the DataOutputStrem and it dose not work now...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried flushing the stream ? Without any other info I'm guessing that your `PrintStream` is storing up the characters but isn't actually outputting them (for efficiency's sake).

See [flush()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#flush%28%29) for more info.

Comment: Note also that [`PrintStream.close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#close%28%29)  *"Closes the stream. This is done by **flushing** the stream and then closing the underlying output stream."*  JavaDoc *quote* by Oracle, **emphasis** by me.

Comment: public  void run() {
  String line; 
   
   try {
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null && line.length()>0) {
     System.out.println("got header line: " + line);
    }
   out.println("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n");
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   out.println("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n");
   out.println("<HTML> <HEAD>hello</HEAD> </HTML>");
   out.println("<HTML> <HEAD>22222</HEAD> </HTML>");
   
    out.flush();


 }

Comment: @Andrew - yes. However I didn't bring close() into the discussion since it wasn't clear to me whether the stream *should* be closed.

Comment: @BrianAgnew  It would seem the thing to do after ending an output string with `</HTML>`.  There is nothing (valid) that could be added after that.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems.
First:  according to HTTP standard:

> The request line and headers must all end with  (that is, a carriage return followed by a line feed).

So, you need to send "\r\n" characters to terminate line.

Also, you are using println function with "\n" character. Println will also add newline character to the end of the string.

So you need to change these lines:

```
ps.println("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
...
ps.println("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
```

to

```
ps.print("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n")
ps.print("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n");
```

And also, dont forget to flush();

Comment: It helped adding this.. How exactly should I use the flush()? and should I use close()?

Comment: Just use ps.flush(); when you are done with you response. If you are not planning to support HTTP keep-alive feature, you can close connection right away.

Comment: another question about ps.println

Comment: It does not go down to a new line